# how to display and group values

Tags: c++

I have data that is state+cities in a column. how can I group or filter them as their corresponding states. partial data in picture.

Comment: `df['your_col'].str.extract('^(\w*):')` would give you the states.

Comment: We need a more varied set of data to work with.  Please post a data set with a few states and a couple of cities in each state, and also post what you want the output to look like.

Comment: `df.groupby('column')`, `df['column'].unique()`

Answer (score 0):

if all states has only 2 character then you can just trim the first 2 indexes of the string

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A':['AZ:Foo','AZ:Bar','AB:Foo','AB:Bar']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['new_column'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x[:2])

df.groupby('new_column')['A'].count()
```

Comment: what if some data does not have first 2 character?

Comment: this was answer above... :) `df['new_column'] = df['A'].str.extract('^(\w*):')`